# strange sizeof result in MVC (alignment?)

Tags: c, alignment, sizeof

The following code gives the result
sizeof(t1)=16 sizeof(t2)=16
I would have expected sizeof(t2)=12 because sizeof(fpos_t)=8 and sizeof(int)=4. Can someone explain this?

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        fpos_t fpos;
        char* s;
        int a;
    } t1;
    typedef struct {
        fpos_t fpos;
        int a;
    } t2;
    t1 it1;
    t2 it2;
    printf("sizeof(t1)=%d sizeof(t2)=%d ", sizeof(t1), sizeof(t2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One word can explain it: *padding*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [alignment reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), compiler is free to insert padding. That means the size of a struct is not necessarily equal to the sum of size of individual members. This is explicitly allowed by the C standard.

The only place where padding is not allowed at the start of a struct i.e. before the first member.

From [C11 draft, 6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.**

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

Most computers now in days only allow allocation at "words" (aka 8 bytes, aka 64 bits) at a time. It's called padding.

Think of it as hotel rooms. Regardless if you have 1 or 2 people (`chars`) staying in the same room (`memory location`), the room will be the same size.